# specifying assembly in layered architecture

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, mapster

I specify mapster service operations in web program.cs in layered architecture, but I want to use this application in another layer. And I'm having trouble choosing assembly.

Web Layer Program.cs

```
var config = TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings;
config.Scan(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserMappingConfig)));
builder.Services.AddSingleton(config);
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMapper, ServiceMapper>();
```

Service Layer Mapping Classes

```
namespace Exams.Service.Mapping
{
    public class QuestionMappingConfig : IRegister
    {
        public void Register(TypeAdapterConfig config)
        {
            config.NewConfig<QuestionViewModel, Question>().IgnoreNullValues(true);
            config.NewConfig<List<QuestionViewModel>,List<Question>>().IgnoreNullValues(true);
            config.NewConfig<Question, QuestionViewModel>().IgnoreNullValues(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting a warning like this

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning CS8604  Possible null reference argument for parameter 'assemblies' in 'IList TypeAdapterConfig.Scan(params Assembly[] assemblies)'.

[image: Program.cs]

[image: NLayerProject]

To summarize, for the Mapster application that I have to define in the Web layer, I want to use the configurations that I defined in the Service layer in the Service layer, but I have trouble choosing the assembly. How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Assembly.GetAssembly` returns `Assembly?` (see [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references)), you can either use null-forgiving operator (`!`):

```cs
config.Scan(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(UserMappingConfig))!);
```

Or just use `Assembly` from the type instance:

```cs
config.Scan(typeof(UserMappingConfig).Assembly);
```